# How to have VPS send its own emails through Exchange hosted at Microsoft?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, exchange, vps

Current setup:

- mydomain.com registered with Dreamhost
- mydomain.com website served by CentOS7 VPS with Media Temple
- mydomain.com email served by Microsoft Office Business Premium

I've got the DNS settings at Dreamhost configured so that mail goes to Microsoft and www requests go to MediaTemple, but I'm stuck on the final bit of config:

How do I allow our VPS to send via `web-server@mydomain.com`? Right now it's sending mail directly instead of through Microsoft and I'm getting spoofing and spam warnings because the origin IP doesn't match that of our email.

To be clear, I'm talking about basic maintenance emails like "my backup was completed successfully" or "I just updated myself" or "new comment on the website", etc.

The VPS is mostly managed with Plesk. I also have ssh / root access.

This seems like a basic thing, but I've had no luck googling up a solution. Is there a `conf` somewhere into which I can add an email username and password? I've done this in the past with smtp, but not with Exchange.

Comment: Which piece(s) of software are sending email? Or do you want the standard sendmail to go via Microsoft? What operating system are you using - Linux I assume? I used SSMTP - I have I tutorial that may be relevant [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#email).

Comment: @Tim, It's CentOS7 and I was referring the standard sendmail when cron jobs complete and such

Answer (score 1):

To perform that you have multiple options:

1. It depends on the application which is sending the emails. For example if you use Joomla to show some kind of website you could configure joomla with an username & password from your Microsoft Exchange server and joomla will send emails then directly via your Exchange server with the email address configured.
2. If that isn´t the case or not possible you might use the local installed sendmail on your VPS and you might need to configure it to relay emails via your hosted MS Exchange environment. Here is a Microsoft [howto](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn751020(v=exchg.150).aspx) to start with.
3. Another option would be to configure the SPF record correctly on your Microsoft Exchange environment and add the IP from the outgoing mailserver from Dreamhost. However that would be shared mailhost and this would mean that other customers could also send emails in the name from your environment and therefore fake emails so that they look like if they where send from your envrionment.

**Conclusion:**
I think solution 1 would be the best option you have.

Comment: I concur with @BastianW that option 1 is probably your best bet.  I've found most website Content Management Systems feature SMTP plugins to easily configure a default email account that authenticates and sends through your Exchange server, otherwise a combination of #2 & #3 are probably needed, especially if your hosting environment is a shared hosting environment.